# Finding left edge colour of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uiview, uiimage

I'm trying to set a `UIView` background colour to the colour of a UIImage's left edge colour. This I think will set the background colour on the `UIView` to match the images background pretty closely.

I have tried average colour and that sometimes doesn't work very well - colour of my `UIView` is normally a few shades off or the wrong shade all together from what the background colour is of the image. So I figured looking at the left edge of the `UIImage` should give us a reasonably accurate representation of the `UIImage`'s background colour.

Doing some searching and looking through SO questions - I found this bit of code, which does exactly what I need. However it is code for OS X and not iOS.

```
    - (NSColor*)findEdgeColor:(NSImage*)image imageColors:(NSCountedSet**)colors
{
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[image representations] lastObject];

    if ( ![imageRep isKindOfClass:[NSBitmapImageRep class]] ) // sanity check
        return nil;

    NSInteger pixelsWide = [imageRep pixelsWide];
    NSInteger pixelsHigh = [imageRep pixelsHigh];

    NSCountedSet *imageColors = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithCapacity:pixelsWide * pixelsHigh];
    NSCountedSet *leftEdgeColors = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithCapacity:pixelsHigh];

    for ( NSUInteger x = 0; x < pixelsWide; x++ )
    {
        for ( NSUInteger y = 0; y < pixelsHigh; y++ )
        {
            NSColor *color = [imageRep colorAtX:x y:y];

            if ( x == 0 )
            {
                [leftEdgeColors addObject:color];
            }

            [imageColors addObject:color];
        }
    }

    *colors = imageColors;


    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [leftEdgeColors objectEnumerator];
    NSColor *curColor = nil;
    NSMutableArray *sortedColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[leftEdgeColors count]];

    while ( (curColor = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil )
    {
        NSUInteger colorCount = [leftEdgeColors countForObject:curColor];

        NSInteger randomColorsThreshold = (NSInteger)(pixelsHigh * kColorThresholdMinimumPercentage);

        if ( colorCount <= randomColorsThreshold ) // prevent using random colors, threshold based on input image height
            continue;

        PCCountedColor *container = [[PCCountedColor alloc] initWithColor:curColor count:colorCount];

        [sortedColors addObject:container];
    }

    [sortedColors sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];


    PCCountedColor *proposedEdgeColor = nil;

    if ( [sortedColors count] > 0 )
    {
        proposedEdgeColor = [sortedColors objectAtIndex:0];

        if ( [proposedEdgeColor.color pc_isBlackOrWhite] ) // want to choose color over black/white so we keep looking
        {
            for ( NSInteger i = 1; i < [sortedColors count]; i++ )
            {
                PCCountedColor *nextProposedColor = [sortedColors objectAtIndex:i];

                if (((double)nextProposedColor.count / (double)proposedEdgeColor.count) > .3 ) // make sure the second choice color is 30% as common as the first choice
                {
                    if ( ![nextProposedColor.color pc_isBlackOrWhite] )
                    {
                        proposedEdgeColor = nextProposedColor;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // reached color threshold less than 40% of the original proposed edge color so bail
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return proposedEdgeColor.color;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do the same thing for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As done in https://github.com/lukaswelte/ColorArt

You can do this via:

```
- (UIColor*)_findEdgeColor:(UIImage*)image imageColors:(NSArray**)colors {

CGImageRef imageRep = image.CGImage;

NSUInteger pixelRange = 32;
NSUInteger scale = 256 / pixelRange;
NSUInteger rawImageColors[pixelRange][pixelRange][pixelRange];
NSUInteger rawEdgeColors[pixelRange][pixelRange][pixelRange]; 
// Should probably just switch to calloc, but this doesn't show up in instruments
// So I guess it's fine
for(NSUInteger b = 0; b < pixelRange; b++) {
    for(NSUInteger g = 0; g < pixelRange; g++) {
        for(NSUInteger r = 0; r < pixelRange; r++) {
            rawImageColors[r][g][b] = 0;
            rawEdgeColors[r][g][b] = 0;
        }
    }
}


NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRep);// [imageRep pixelsWide];
NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRep); //[imageRep pixelsHigh];

CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, cs, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, (CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width = width, .size.height = height}, image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);
const RGBAPixel* pixels = (const RGBAPixel*)CGBitmapContextGetData(bmContext);
for (NSUInteger y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (NSUInteger x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        const NSUInteger index = x + y * width;
        RGBAPixel pixel = pixels[index];
        Byte r = pixel.red / scale;
        Byte g = pixel.green / scale;
        Byte b = pixel.blue / scale;
        rawImageColors[r][g][b] = rawImageColors[r][g][b] + 1;
        if(0 == x) {
            rawEdgeColors[r][g][b] = rawEdgeColors[r][g][b] + 1;
        }
    }
}
CGContextRelease(bmContext);

NSMutableArray* imageColors = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* edgeColors = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSUInteger b = 0; b < pixelRange; b++) {
    for(NSUInteger g = 0; g < pixelRange; g++) {
        for(NSUInteger r = 0; r < pixelRange; r++) {
            NSUInteger count = rawImageColors[r][g][b];
            if(count > _randomColorThreshold) {
                UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r / (CGFloat)pixelRange green:g / (CGFloat)pixelRange blue:b / (CGFloat)pixelRange alpha:1];
                PCCountedColor* countedColor = [[PCCountedColor alloc] initWithColor:color count:count];
                [imageColors addObject:countedColor];
            }

            count = rawEdgeColors[r][g][b];
            if(count > _randomColorThreshold) {
                UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r / (CGFloat)pixelRange green:g / (CGFloat)pixelRange blue:b / (CGFloat)pixelRange alpha:1];
                PCCountedColor* countedColor = [[PCCountedColor alloc] initWithColor:color count:count];
                [edgeColors addObject:countedColor];
            }
        }
    }
}

*colors = imageColors;

NSMutableArray* sortedColors = edgeColors;
[sortedColors sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

PCCountedColor *proposedEdgeColor = nil;

if ( [sortedColors count] > 0 )
{
    proposedEdgeColor = [sortedColors objectAtIndex:0];

    if ( [proposedEdgeColor.color pc_isBlackOrWhite] ) // want to choose color over black/white so we keep looking
    {
        for ( NSInteger i = 1; i < [sortedColors count]; i++ )
        {
            PCCountedColor *nextProposedColor = [sortedColors objectAtIndex:i];

            if (((double)nextProposedColor.count / (double)proposedEdgeColor.count) > .4 ) // make sure the second choice color is 40% as common as the first choice
            {
                if ( ![nextProposedColor.color pc_isBlackOrWhite] )
                {
                    proposedEdgeColor = nextProposedColor;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // reached color threshold less than 40% of the original proposed edge color so bail
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

return proposedEdgeColor.color;
}
```

If you want just the left edge, you can achieve this by simply excluding the for loop for the other edges.

Comment: Thanks,. I am trying to use it but the colour it returns is completely wrong. Which loops do I exclude for all edges besides left? Thank you!

Comment: You Need to be sure you pass in scaled image. i would suggest you have a look into the complete slcolorart class to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks I looked through the docs and example code. colour is better. But not perfect. Any suggestions? Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Could you post your sample image?

Comment: I found the problem - which is not related to the question posted here. The code is sometimes executed and sometimes not - due to image downloading. I need to find out why its failing. However for this question I am satirised with the answer as it has helped me a great deal. I will post another question on my other issue. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I can only award my bounty in 22hr time. So I will make a point of doing it tomorrow for you.

Comment: A perfect. Good luck on resolving your other issue.